# Alternative to `sed -i` on Solaris

Tags: shell, unix, sed, solaris

On Linux `sed -i` will modify the input files in place. It doesn't work on Solaris, though.

```
sed -i '$ s/OLD/NEW/g' test        
sed: illegal option -- i
```

What can I use in place of `sed -i` on Solaris?

Comment: *On Linux `sed -i` will modify the input files in place.* Not really - [GNU `sed -i` creates a new temp file and then renames it to the original file name, deleting the original file in the process.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to replicate `-i`'s behavior yourself by storing the results in a temp file and then replacing the original file with the temp file. This may seem inelegant but that's all `sed -i` is doing under the covers.

```
sed '$ s/OLD/NEW/g' test > test.tmp && cat test.tmp > test && rm test.tmp
```

If you care you could make it a bit more robust by using `mktemp`:

```
tmp=$(mktemp test.XXXXXX)
sed '$ s/OLD/NEW/g' test > "$tmp" && cat "$tmp" > test && rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: Alternatively, copy the original to temp file, redirect the command to overwrite the original (reinstate if the command fails), then remove the copy.

Answer (score 26):

It isn't exactly the same as sed -i, but i had a similar issue. You can do this using perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g' file
```

doing the copy/move only works for single files. if you want to replace some text across every file in a directory and sub-directories, you need something which does it in place. you can do this with perl and find:

```
find . -exec perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g' '{}' \;
```

Comment: doesn't work well when the string being found/replaced contains slashes and single quotes. tried escaping those characters with no luck.

Comment: The complete answer is, it works with GNU sed. You could install GNU sed in Solaris and enjoy. If not possible, a way to make it work with Solaris sed is:
`( rm -f myfile ; sed 's/../../' > myfile) < myfile`. _Credit: http://board.issociate.de/thread/460042/_

Comment: which is a different way of implement John's solution above. ^_^

Answer (score -1):

One more "one-line" command which works on Solaris 11 host in bash enviroment:

```
for i in `cat strings_to_delete.txt`
do 
    sed "/$i/d" file.to_edit.txt > file.edited.txt &&
        mv file.edited.txt file.to_edit.txt
done
```

It deletes strings from file `strings_to_delete.txt` in `file.to_edit.txt`. File `strings_to_delete.txt` contains multiple lines with one string per line.

Comment: What's new about this?  That's exactly the same as existing answer (write to a temp file and if successful, move it over the original).

Comment: There is no new info about tmp file, but there is info how to delete multiple strings using sed which I miss in previous conversation. Well, maybe not the right thread.

Comment: It looses the original permissions.