# sed -i option is not working on solaris

Tags: unix, sed, solaris

I am using sed to replace a line with NULL in a file. The command i used is

```
sed -i "s/.*shayam.*//g" FILE
```

This is working fine in linux. shayam is replaced with blank in the FILE. But when i used this in solaris it is showing some error.

> sed: illegal option -- i

How to use -i functionality of sed in solaris. Kindly help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-i` option is GNU-specific. The Solaris version does not support the option.

You will need to install the GNU version, or rename the new file over the old one:

```
sed 's/.shayam.//g' FILE > FILE.new && mv FILE.new FILE
```

Comment: Using mktemp helps to ensure that we don't inadvertantly step on any files named FILE.new ... tmp=$(mktemp) && sed -e 's/.*shayam.*//g' FILE > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" FILE; rm "$tmp" 2> /dev/null

Answer (score 12):

I just answered a similar question [sed -i + what the same option in SOLARIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/sed-i-what-the-same-option-in-solaris/4314796#4314796), but for those who find this thread instead (I saw it in the related thread section):

The main problem I see with most answers given is that it doesn't work if you want to modify multiple files. The answer I gave in the other thread:

> It isn't exactly the same as sed -i, but i had a similar issue. You
>   can do this using perl:
>
> ```
> perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g' file
> ```
>
> doing the copy/move only works for single files. if you want to
>   replace some text across every file in a directory and
>   sub-directories, you need something which does it in place. you can do
>   this with perl and find:
>
> ```
> find . -exec perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g' '{}' \;
> ```

Answer (score 3):

[`sed` doesn't haven an `-i` option](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

You are probably using some vendor-specific variant of `sed`. If you want to use the vendor-specific non-standardized extensions of your vendor-specific non-standardized variant of `sed`, you need to make sure that you install said vendor-specific non-standardized variant and need to make sure that you call *it* and don't call the standards-compliant version of `sed` that is part of your operating environment.

Note that as always when using non-standardized vendor-specific extensions, there is absolutely no guarantee that your code will be portable, which is exactly the problem you are seeing.

In this particular case, however, there is a much better solution: use the right tool for the job. `sed` is a *stream editor* (that's why it is *called* "sed"), i.e. it is for editing streams, not files. If you want to edit files, use a *file editor*, such as [`ed`](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html):

```
ed FILE <<-HERE
  ,s/.shayam.//g
  w
  q
HERE
```

See also:

- [Unable to use SED to edit files fast](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/722699/#722942)
- [How can I replace a specific line by line number in a text file?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/703459/#703535)

Answer (score 0):

Either `cat` the file or try `<`?
Then pipe (`|`) the result to a temp file and if all goes well (`&&`) `mv` the tempfile to the original file.

Example:

```
cat my_file | sed '!A!B!' > my_temp_file && mv my_temp_file my_file
```