# how to edit file at remote server?

Tags: unix, sed, solaris

i want to edit file at remote server using solaris

the original file at the remote server that i want to edit is :

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
```

and i want to remove the 5th line "55555" and replace it by "00000"

i try this

```
ssh user@host 'cat ~/path_of_original_file.txt '| sed 's/55555/00000/g' ;
```

the result appears successfully and the line replaced as i want , but when i open the file at the remote server nothing change !!!!!

Comment: You are changing the stdout, not the file itself. To replace in place you need to do `sed -i 's/55555/00000/g' file`

Comment: thank you for replay ,,,,,,, i try but it respond with "sed: illegal option -- i"

Comment: Ok then it means that `-i` is not possible. You can then store the output in a temp file and then move to the original: `sed 's/55555/00000/g' file > temp_file && mv temp_file file`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your attempt:

1. You pipe the `cat`ed output to `sed`, so you are only changing `stdout`.
2. The right-hand-side of the pipe is run *locally*, *not* on the remote server since it is outside of your quoted string.

What you probably want is

```
ssh user@host 'sed -i "s/55555/00000/g" ~/path_of_original_file.txt'
```

where `-i` means in-place (see `man sed`).

Also note that `/g` will change all occurrances of `55555`, not just the first/the one on line 5.

Since you are on Solaris and your `sed` probably doesn't have `-i` you need to use a temporary file (see also e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/sed-i-what-the-same-option-in-solaris)).

Comment: thank you very much ,,,,, ^_^ i am new in unix so i still make lots of mistakes ,, i will try and tell you what happen