# Linux Shell Programming. Implementing a Search, Find and Replace Technique

Tags: linux, shell, unix, replace, find

I have to implement an application in shell programming (Unix/Linux).

I have to search a word from a text file and replace that word with my given word. I have a knowledge on shell and still learning.

I am not expecting source code. Can anybody help me or suggest me or give me some similar solution....

Comment: You can for example use `grep` to find text in a file, `find` to find a file and `sed` for replacements. Check man page of each one of them (`man grep`, `man sed`...).

Comment: `embedded-linux` seems an odd tag for this question, as does `linux-kernel`

Comment: You want to have a look at sed, especially its s command.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat abc.txt | grep "pattern" | sed 's/"pattern"/"new pattern"/g'
```

The above command should work

Thanks,

Regards,

Dheeraj Rampally

Comment: I smell a "useless use of cat" award...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Say you are looking for `pattern` in a file (`input.txt`) and want to replace it with `"new pattern"` in another (`output.txt`)

Here is the main idea, without UUOC:

```
<input.txt sed 's/"pattern"/"new pattern"/g' >output.txt
```

---

### todo

Now you need to embed this line in your program. You may want to make it interactive, or a command that you could use with 3 parameters.

---

### edit

I tried to avoid the use of output.txt as a temporary file with this:

```
<input.txt sed 's/"pattern"/"new pattern"/g' >input.txt
```

but it empties `input.txt` for a reason I can't understand. So I tried with a subshell, so:

```
echo $(<input.txt sed 's/pattern/"new pattern"/g')>input.txt
```

... but the `echo` command removes line breaks... still looking.

---

### edit2

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place , it looks like writing to the very same file at once it not easy at all. However, I could do what I wanted with `sed -i` for [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) only:

```
sed -i 's/pattern/"new pattern"/g' input.txt
```

From [sed -i + what the same option in SOLARIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/sed-i-what-the-same-option-in-solaris) , it looks like there's no alternative, and you must use a temporary file:

```
sed 's/pattern/"new pattern"/g' input.txt > input.tmp && mv input.tmp input.txt
```