# Change AWK field separator on the fly

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'd like to use AWK to take the following spread sheet where the first name and last name are in one column:

```
Peter Griffin, 31 Spooner St, Quahog
Homer Simpson, 732 Evergreen Terr, Springfield
Fred Flintstone, 301 Cobblestone Way, Bedrock
```

and output to a new spreadsheet where the first name and last name have their own columns:

```
Peter, Griffin, 31 Spooner St, Quahog
Homer, Simpson, 732 Evergreen Terr, Springfield
Fred, Flintstone, 301 Cobblestone Way, Bedrock
```

I've tried changing field separators on the fly doing something like:

```
awk '{print $1 "," $2} {FS=","} {print $3} {FS=" "}' spreadsheet.csv
```

but it doesn't seem to work that way, and I get a jumbled mess.  Is this possible using AWK?

Comment: Does the full name always consist of exactly two words?

Comment: FYI a comma is a terrible field separator for a name/address spreadsheet as they are commonly used within names and addresses. You should use a tab instead.

Comment: Hey @Ed, do you know why updating FS doesn't work here? I couldn't find an explanation in POSIX spec

Comment: @oguzismail because the OP is setting the FS to `,` **after** the record has already been split into fields and then setting it back to `" "` again before splitting the next record.

Comment: @Ed Oh yeah, but, is there a way to force awk to resplit fields after changing FS?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes - `$0=$0`.

Comment: @Ed Ohh I don't know how did I miss that.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a comma whenever a space is found in the first `,`-based field:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {sub(/ /, ", ", $1)}1' file
#                             ^    ^^
#               find a space...    ... replace it with , plus space
```

With your file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {sub(/ /, ", ", $1)}1' file
Peter, Griffin, 31 Spooner St, Quahog
Homer, Simpson, 732 Evergreen Terr, Springfield
Fred, Flintstone, 301 Cobblestone Way, Bedrock
```

This uses the function [`sub()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) to perform the replacement in the first field.

Comment: Not `whenever a space` but `when the first space` otherwise `Harry Connick Jr` can't be in your database :-). Your code is correct it's just your text that's wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton uhms, true, although thinking about it maybe `gsub()` just on `$1` may be best, since you Americans have a lot of senior, jr and III in your names ;D

Comment: @fedorqui This is what I was looking for, thanks!  What is the purpose of the 1 after the closing curly brace?  I notice that I can put any number in place of the 1 and the command still works.

Comment: @RyanR yes this is because `1`, `5` or any number evaluates to True and triggers awk's default action, consisting in printing the current line. So `1` is equivalent to `{print $0}`.

Comment: `you Americans`? I'm not American. I'm Scottish. Anyway, if you add more commas it'll break the (ill-advised!) comma-separated layout of the OPs file.

Comment: @fedorqui your comment is still there on my screen, idk why you're not seeing it. I didn't find it offensive, just inaccurate :-)., so I certainly didn't flag it anyway. Yes, the OP wants to create exactly 2 fields out of that one field.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the first space with a comma-space:

```
$ sed 's/ /, /' file.csv
Peter, Griffin, 31 Spooner St, Quahog
Homer, Simpson, 732 Evergreen Terr, Springfield
Fred, Flintstone, 301 Cobblestone Way, Bedrock
```

Here, `s/ /, /` is a substitute command.  It replaces the first  found with `,`.

To change the file in place, use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i.bak 's/ /, /' file.csv
```

Comment: The in-place option is a GNU extension, and does not work in unix/solaris.

Comment: @DanielListon You are right about [solaris sed not having a `-i` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/alternative-to-sed-i-on-solaris).  The -`i option is not required by POSIX but it is available on GNU sed, MacOS sed, and [FreeBSD sed](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed).  The OP tagged this question for Linux.

Comment: Understood.  However, the OP requested and tagged an AWK solution, not sed.  If an alternate solution is offered, it should be clear there is a difference between utilities with the same name offered by GNU and their original program versions.  Especially if a modifier provided in an example does not work across ALL unix/linux platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility.

```
awk '{$1=$1","}1' file

Peter, Griffin, 31 Spooner St, Quahog
Homer, Simpson, 732 Evergreen Terr, Springfield
Fred, Flintstone, 301 Cobblestone Way, Bedrock
```

Comment: What does the 1 after } I tried with other number and we have same result. I can't find in the man I even read awk source code but can't guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple separators as-

```
awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $1 ", " $2 ", " $3 $4 " " $5 " " $6 ", " $7 " " $8}' file
```

Output-

```
Peter, Griffin,  31 Spooner St,  Quahog
Homer, Simpson,  732 Evergreen Terr,  Springfield
Fred, Flintstone,  301 Cobblestone Way,  Bedrock
```

You have to keep a track of the 'columns' that get defined though.

Comment: Don't do that. It's unnecessarily hard-coding everything and will fail when the address is any other format, e.g. `19 Martin Luther King Dr` or the name is `Harry Connick Jr`.

Comment: Yup, this becomes a specific solution. Not portable at all. But it addresses the problem of how to use multiple separators in the same awk line.

Comment: But using multiple separators is the wrong approach to this question as it adds more problems than it solves and if it were necessary you'd write it as `-F '[ ,]'`, not `-F ' |,'` (consider the difference if you had 10 separator characters).

Comment: Conceded. Edited to reflect the better way.