# need help to edit the sudoer on solaris through script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

```
When i am trying in solaris its throughing the below error
```

# cat /usr/local/etc/sudoers |grep -i unix
  unix   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
 root on test:

## sed -i -e 's/^\s*(unix\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*NOPASSWD:\s*ALL)/#\1/' /usr/local/etc/sudoers

```
sed: illegal option -- i
root on test:</tmp>
```

i have tried this also its also not working

```
root on test: </tmp>
$ sudo perl -pi -e 's/^\s*\(unix\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*NOPASSWD:\s*ALL\)/#\1/' /usr/local/etc/sudoers

root on test: </tmp>
cat /usr/local/etc/sudoers |grep -i unix
unix   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL


sed -i -e 's/^\s*\(unix\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*NOPASSWD:\s*ALL\)/#\1/' /usr/local/etc/sudoers but the same script is working on linux
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed -i + what the same option in SOLARIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/sed-i-what-the-same-option-in-solaris)

Comment: i want to comment unix entry through scrit # cat /usr/local/etc/sudoers |grep -i unix
unix   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
root on test:</tmp>

#sed -i + 's/^\s*\(unix\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*NOPASSWD:\s*ALL\)/#\1/' /usr/local/etc/sudoers
sed: illegal option -- i
root on test:</tmp>

Comment: i want to comment unix entry through script                                             # cat /usr/local/etc/sudoers |grep -i unix
unix   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
root on test:</tmp>

#sed -i + 's/^\s*\(unix\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*NOPASSWD:\s*ALL\)/#\1/' /usr/local/etc/sudoers
sed: illegal option -- i
root on test:</tmp>                                                                                                            i am getting illegal option error