# How to use "SED -i" in solaris?

Tags: solaris

```
-bash-3.2$ cat sed
A
B
C
D
-bash-3.2$ sed -i '$ a\sedtest' sed 
sed: illegal option -- i
-bash-3.2$
```

I cant use  { echo "sedtest" >> sed }

-bash-3.2$ cat sed
A
B
C
D
-bash-3.2$ sed -i '$ a\sedtest' sed 
sed: illegal option -- i
-bash-3.2$

Any solution using awk/perl/sed?

Comment: `sed '$ a\sedtest' sed > tmp && mv tmp sed`?

Comment: please make sure if this is already answered somewhere else or easily googled:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/alternative-to-sed-i-on-solaris

Comment: `-i` is a non-standard, non-portable GNU extension to the [POSIX standard `sed` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-i` flag is an addition of GNU sed over the traditional Unix sed.  On Solaris 11, you can use GNU sed by running `/usr/gnu/bin/sed` - on Solaris 10, you'll need to install the GNU sed open source package as it's not provided with the OS.

Comment: Thanks, Alanc, that's exactly what I am looking for. I tried your solution and booomm it is working. Also now I can use /usr/xpg4/bin/sed @alanc Thanks